# Multiple axes graph highcharts.js server upload/download line graph with bar on x-axis for server up/down

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I'm stuck making a graph exactly like this. I searched a lot and found high charts can do it. I've to show upload and download speed on y-axis and a bar chart on x-axis that shows green colour when server is up and red when server is down. below it comes the date which is also on x axis. I'm unable to do it. I've made the bar graphs for server up/down time and the upload/download speed.
I just want a way to merge them to show them in one graph exactly as in
[image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9seSsqMTwxTYVJXM3FkbVF1NWc&authuser=0).
I've written code for upload download graph

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },

     plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            lineWidth: 2 

            },

        },

        series: [{

        color: '#FCBC15'
    },
                 {

        color: '#002453'
    }
                ],

    title: {
        text: 'Average User Connection Speed'
    },

    data: {
         csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    }
});
```

});

Now below is the code for server up time down time

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Title',
                style: { fontSize: '17px', color: 'Black', fontWeight: 'bold', fontfamily: 'Times New Roman' }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                'May 1',
                'May 2',
                'May 3',
                'May 4'
            ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Attributes Scores'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    minPointLength: 0
                }
            },
        series: [{
                name: ' ',
                color: "",
                data: [1, 0, 1, 1]


                // data: eval('(' + seriesYTD + ')')


            }
                ],

  exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, function (chart) {



            $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (i, data) {

                if (data.y < 1){
                    data.y=data.y+1;
                    data.update({
                        color: '#FF0000'
                    });
                }
                else
                    data.update({
                        color: '#00B14A'
                    });



            });



        });
```

});

Comment: There are a number of ways to go about this. I would not be using categories anywhere for any of this though - do you really measure up/down time in terms of full days?  It might be easier to do this as two separate charts that sit one above the other, as an inverted columnrange chart type or stacked horizontal bar would be the best way to build the bar, and it won't work on the same chart with your regular line series.  If you can put up live fiddle examples it will be easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: The problem is that I am to make exactly same graph as in image. I'm stuck too bad. here are jsfiddle examples of above codes. http://jsfiddle.net/mahad/7adnc1aj/     http://jsfiddle.net/mahad/hrewauxk/